# Lenovo Flex 3-1480 laptop wont boot after Ubuntu 20,04 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, updates

I replied to this question, but someone deleted my post:

Dell XPS13 9310 boot issues after latest security updates/Ubuntu Base - 20.04.1

I have a similar problem with a Lenovo Flex 3-1480 laptop. After the update, the dialog said Restart required. I clicked the later button then shutdown. them immediately rebooted after it shutdown. Linux never came up. After about 10 minutes I shut it down and tried again. Te GRUB menu came up with a 25 second delay. I have this set to 2 seconds! I don't recall seeing the GRUB menu screen the first time.

The next day, I waited 49 minutes for Ubuntu to come up. It didn't. I successfully booted to Windows 10 on the same machine, proving it is an Ubuntu issue, not the hardware.

I haven't tried to boot my Ubuntu 20.01 install Flash yet. I'm not sure the best way to fix it, if I did that.

What is the best way to recover?

P.S. Why was my response deleted? I really need some help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is probably to boot from a Live Ubuntu USB (make sure the USB stick comes first in the BIOS boot order), and do `sudo update-grub`, then see if it already fixed the problem. If it doesn't, try reinstalling GRUB.

Your answer to the other question was probably deleted because it was *not* an answer, as in an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: As GRUB seemed to be working, I tried to boot an older kernel. I selected advanced options for Ubuntu 20, the second kernel: Ubuntu 5.4.0-53-generic. This failed to boot.  I then tried the first line -54- and the third line -52-, neither booted. Then I booted in recovery mode with -53-. This booted! I viewed the information screen. Everything looked OK. I tried fsck. That failed without running. I don't recall the error. Finally, I tried continue to normal boot with -53-. That booted OK! From there, I did a software update. One of the updates was to remove kernel -54-. Several reboots worked!

Comment: A few days later it still failed to boot. I installed rEFInd boot manager from: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind. This gave a security violation. I figured out how to disable Secure Boot in the UEFI settings. Ubuntu 20 still won't boot. I've been having issues with the a USB flash like the one I have installed Ubuntu 20 on. So, I installed Ubuntu 20 on the Hard drive. This came up right after install and did a large update. It didn't reboot after that.It didn't reboot after that. Now the HDD and USB flash install fail the same way. I guess it is NOT the flash drive.  Continued ...

Comment: I did discover that I can boot in the recovery mode, then continue normal boot. This boots to Ubuntu 20! Unfortunately, only one low resolution video mode is supported. This makes my 24" monitor of little use. How do I figure out what is wrong with normal boot? Is there some way to add high red modes to recovery boot?

Comment: The latest update, with kernel: vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic, fixed this problem. Normal boot now works. Recovery boot is not needed. High res mode now works as before. Thanks to whoever did this!

Comment: The next time I tried to boot, Dec 25, it failed! It did boot in recovery mode at Low Res. Dec 26 it booted OK, which is odd as there were no updates. Ubuntu MATE 18.10 also boooted OK. It always does. Dec 28 Ubuntu 20 failed to boot! It also failed to boot in recovery mode! This is rare! Ubuntu MATE 18.10 did boot OK. NOTE: I have another computer, an Acer which always boots.

Comment: Hmm! I just read the news that Ubuntu 21.04 is failing to boot on older machines! Seems quite similar to this bug!